# Connect Mulesoft and Aurora RDS

Tags: ssh, database-connection, amazon-aurora, mulesoft

I’m trying to connect my database mysql (RDS Aurora serverless) and Mulesoft. But I have to setup an SSH tunnel with an EC2 instance (AWS restrictions) So I try an ssh connection from Mulesoft to my EC2 instance, all tutorials I have found talk about sshmultiplexedconnector or SSH Connecter - Mule 3, and they seems to be deprecated.

Did you had the same problems, and do you have solutions or other methods ?

PS, I’m using : Mule server 4.2.0 Anypoint Studio 7.3.4 EC2 instance run Ubuntu 18.04

Tutorial : https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/connectivity-dev/mule-in-a-shell-new-ssh-connector/

Thanks and regards.

[mule-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPu6k.png)
[mule-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzRCG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box connector for Mule 4 that implements an SSH tunnel. The connector you mentioned is for Mule 3, so it is not compatible, and hasn't been maintained for some years. You could attempt to build a connector for Mule 4 to do it, however I would argue that a communication tunnel, same as a VPN, is task better implemented at the server level. Just do it from your operating system and to the Mule application it should be transparent.